# How to make 2 columns from one in one select in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got one database with two columns (`id` and `value`). There are two types of values and each id has both of this values. How can I make a select to this database to have three columns in result (`id`, `value1` and `value2`)

I've tried `CASE` and `GROUP BY`, but it shows only one result of each id

Example of a db:

```
| id | value |  
|  0 | a     |  
|  0 | b     |  
|  1 | a     |  
|  1 | b     |
```

Example of the result I am looking for is:

```
| id | value_a | value_b |  
| 0  | a       | b       |  
| 1  | a       | b       |
```

---

UPDATE:

As it was noted in comments, there is too simple data in the example.

The problem is more complicated
An example that would better describe it:

DB:

```
| id | value | value2 | value3 |  
|  0 | a     | a2     | a3     |  
|  0 | b     | b2     | b3     |  
|  1 | a     | c2     | c3     |  
|  1 | b     | d2     | d3     |
```

RESULT:

```
| id | value_a | value_b | value2_a | value2_b | value3_a | value3_b |   
| 0  | a       | b       | a2       | b2       | a3       | b3       | 
| 1  | a       | b       | c2       | d2       | c3       | d3       |
```

The output should be sorted by id an have all info from the both rows of each id.

Comment: Your example is lacking enough sample data. Put a few more rows for different `id` and put other values apart from `a` and `b`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do:  `select distinct id, 'a', 'b' from t`?  How do you distinguish the values?

Answer (score 1):

If there are always two values per ID, you can try an aggregation using `min()` and `max()`.

```
SELECT id,
       min(value) value_a,
       max(value) value_b
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t0.id,t0.Value as Value_A, t1.Value as Value_B 
from test t0
inner join test t1 on t0.id = t1.id
where t0.Value = 'a' and t1.value = 'b';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method to turn "rows" into "columns". Depending on the number of unique `value`s that exist in the table, you may or may not want to use this :)

```
SELECT id, SUM(CASE WHEN value = "a" then 1 else 0 END) value_a,
     SUM(CASE WHEN value = "b" then 1 else 0 END) value_b,
     SUM(CASE WHEN value = "c" then 1 else 0 END) value_c,
     SUM(CASE WHEN value ="a2" then 1 else 0 END) value_a2,
     .
     .
     .
 FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers! This is the way how I did this:

```
WITH a_table AS  
(  
SELECT id, value, value2, value3 FROM table1 WHERE table1.value = 0  
),  
b_table AS  
(  
SELECT id, value, value2, value3 FROM table1 WHERE table1.value = 1  
)  
SELECT DISTINCT  
a_table.id AS id,  
a_table.value AS value_a,  
a_table.value2 AS value2_a,  
a_table.value3 AS value3_a,  
b_table.value AS value_b,  
b_table.value2 AS value2_b,  
b_table.value3 AS value3_b  
FROM a_table  
JOIN b_table ON a_table.id = b_table.id  
GROUP BY id;
```